# WebControl.Image a Itextsharp.Image

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Tengo el siguiente codigo que convierte un blob de una base de datos a una url de  imagen (`WebControls.Image`):

```
    OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
                cmd2.Connection = conn1;
                cmd2.CommandText = "select simbolo from simbolos_ll where idsimb=" + id;
                OracleDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                dr2.Read();
                OracleLob blob = null;
                blob = dr2.GetOracleLob(0);
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])blob.Value;
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                url = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

De esta manera lo paso a un `List<string>` paras tener las url de las `Img` almacenadas (Lo hago en el codigo pero no quiero mostrar un tochaco):

```
  List<string> imgPDF = new List<string>();
```

Partiendo de este punto, tengo que: Con la Url de la imagen crear una `itextSharp.Image`.

```
  iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagenesPDF[idBlob-1]);
```

Y me salta el siguiente error:

> ```
> "The URI prefix is not recognized."
> ```

La pregunta es la siguiente:
Teniendo la `url`de la imagen, **¿cómo puedo crear la imagen de `itextSharp.Image`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solucione mi problema por mi mismo.
El problema era que el formato de uri no era el correcto, asi que, como `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance();` tiene muchas maneras de generarse y una de ellas es la de pasandole una cadena de bits, fue lo que hize de la siguiente manera:

```
    while (dr2.Read())
    {
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dr2[0];
        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);
        imagenesPDF.Add(img);
    }
```

De esta manera cargo el `Blob` en bits y se lo paso directamente al constructor.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda a todos. Espero que a alguien le sirba esto

Comment: Estupendo! No hay nada más satisfactorio que encontrar la respuesta a un problema por si mismo jeje. Para que esto quede útil para consulta, marca la respuesta que soluciona el problema (tu misma autorespuesta por ejemplo) como aceptada, así la pregunta no se queda sin resolver y queda la respuesta validada para evitar confusiones en posteriores consultas.

Answer (score 1):

El problema con el que te estás encontrando es que la `URI` que puede interpretar `iTextSharp` tiene que ir sin el prefijo data.

Para solucionar esto tendríamos varias opciones:

### Opción 1: Quitar el prefijo data

```
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagenesPDF[idBlob-1].Replace("data:image/png;base64,",""));
```

Añadimos el `replace` para eliminar el prefijo que le está molestando pasándole únicamente la imagen en `StringBase64`.

Si el hecho de que pongas el prefijo `data` es solamente para usarlo con `iTextSharp`, podrías ahorrarte el añadirlo y debería de funcionar correctamente.

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
url = base64String;
```

Ahí nos ahorramos de añadirle el prefijo y obtenemos únicamente la imagen en formato `StringBase64`.

### Opción 2: Pasarle directamente el array de bytes de la imagen

Con la premisa de antes, donde se utiliza únicamente la imagen obtenida de la base de datos para procesarla con `iTextSharp`, podemos directamente pasarle el array de bytes.

Así en lugar de guardar una lista de strings, guardamos una lista de array de bytes y los usamos directamente.

Por poner un código análogo al que nos pasas, sería así:

```
List<byte[]> imgPDF = new List<byte[]>();

OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
                cmd2.Connection = conn1;
                cmd2.CommandText = "select simbolo from simbolos_ll where idsimb=" + id;
                OracleDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                dr2.Read();
                OracleLob blob = null;
                blob = dr2.GetOracleLob(0);
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])blob.Value;
                imgPDF.Add(bytes);
```

Y la última línea se queda sin modificaciones.

```
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagenesPDF[idBlob-1]);
```

`imagenesPDF` ahora sería un array de bytes y la instancia de la imagen de `iTextSharp` debería ejecutarse correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo ahora iba a autoresponderme la pregunta con como solucione el problema. Muchas gracias por tu esfuerzo de todas formas.